Inner product in RKHS
I am reading a paper and am confused by an expression about the inner product.
It says that
"Given a scalar-valued RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ with a positive definite kernel $k(x,x')$, $\cdots$ and $<\cdot, \cdot>_{\mathcal{H}}$" is a inner product on $\mathcal{H}$".
What is the from of the inner product? I am asking because we need to define it in Hilbert space, like it is a vector dot product or integral of functions, etc. Right?
What is inner product in this context?

The inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathcal H}$ can be any scalar product so that

$(\mathcal H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathcal H})$  is a Hilbert space of functions
$\delta_x\colon \mathcal H\to \mathbb R,\; f\mapsto f(x)$ is continuous for every $x$ in the domain $\mathfrak X$ (i.e. $\mathcal H\subseteq \mathbb R^{\mathfrak X}$) w.r.t. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathcal H}$.

If you have this, you can choose the Riesz representative of $\delta_x$ for each $x\in\mathfrak X$, canonically denoted by $k(\cdot,x)\in\mathcal H$, that is $$f(x)=\delta_x(f)=\langle f,k(\cdot,x)\rangle_{\mathcal H}$$ for all $f\in\mathcal H$ and thus obtain your kernel $k(\cdot,\cdot)$.
Moore-Aronszajn's theorem, on the other hand, ensures the opposite direction. So if you have a kernel $k(\cdot,\cdot)$, it generates a uniquely determined RKHS $\mathcal H(k)$. The idea of the proof is to first look at the space $$H_0:=\operatorname{lin}\{k(\cdot, x): x \in \mathfrak X\}.$$ For $$
f:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot k\left(\cdot, x_i\right)\in H_0 \quad \text { and } \quad g:=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \cdot k\left(\cdot, x_i\right)\in H_0
$$ with $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb R$ and $x_i\in\mathfrak X$, a inner product can be defined by \begin{align}
\langle f, g\rangle_{H_0}:=\sum_{i, j=1}^n a_i b_j \cdot k\left(x_i, x_j\right).\tag{1}\label{gl}
\end{align}
You then already have the reproducing property in this space, i.e:
$$f(x)=\langle f,k(\cdot,x)\rangle_{H_0}\quad \forall f\in H_0, x\in\mathfrak X,$$ but $H_0$ is in general not complete. By abstract completion (and an isometry back to a function space) you can close $H_0$ in such a way that the reproducing property is still fulfilled. So you get a Hilbert space of functions $(H,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_H)$ that satisfies the reproducing property with $k(\cdot,\cdot)$ and for which $H_0\subseteq H$ applies, but this transition is (to my knowledge) generally not constructive, so you cannot generally derive the form of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$ here (but you can for functions from $H_0$ via \eqref{gl}). I hope this answers your question.
